# Import db in android application

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to import db in my application.But it fails, i am getting fileNotFountException.Please help me to import a db in my application.I got the backup of my db successful in my device memory.why do i get filenotfoundexception.I stored my backup of my db in dbname.db

```
  private void importDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {

            System.out.println("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK");
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//" + "dbname.db" ;
            String backupDBPath = "Restore.db"; // From SD directory.

            System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
            File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
            System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaa");
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFH");
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

My exception

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.rr.remainder/databases/dbname.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-22 06:02:36.486 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
09-22 06:02:36.486 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at com.example.rr.remainder.restore.importDB(restore.java:84)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at com.example.rr.remainder.restore.access$100(restore.java:15)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at com.example.rr.remainder.restore$2.onClick(restore.java:35)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4741)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19384)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
09-22 06:02:36.496 21445-21445/com.example.rr.remainder W/System.err:   ... 15 more
```

Comment: Try with this                                                                                                               
  String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + /data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "dbname.db";

Comment: Its not working sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the subdir */databases* does not exist when you are trying to create the *"dbname.db"* file.

Consider using the following code that will auto create a subdirectory in the application's sandbox if it does not already exist:

```
public void copyBackupDb(){
    File subDirPath = mContext.getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File currentDBFile = new File(subDirPath , "dbname.db");

    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File backupDBFile = new File(sd,"Restore.db");

    try {
        copy(backupDBFile, currentDBFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*mContext is a Context reference from your Andriod Activity or Service.

Comment: String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//" + "dbname.db" ;
                String backupDBPath = "Restore.db"; // From SD directory.



                File subDirPath = context.getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                File dbFilePath = new File(subDirPath , "dbname.db");  I gave like this..But its not working

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a static copy method that replaces your usage of FileChannels. Hope this will help.

Comment: same exception sir: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Restore.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) in lines  try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src))   , , copy(backupDBFile, currentDBFile);   copyBackupDb();

Comment: Its not the same error. The original error referred to the destination file (dbname.db) and not the source. Please make sure that you indeed push a file to  /storage/emulated/0/Restore.db before you perform your test.

Comment: sorry sir, i didn't get u